# Comparing objects from two different classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hello I have been stuck on trying to figure this out. I am passing an object in this function to compare two different volumes, however I am required to use two different classes (inheritance) in order to receive the information for the volume. When I try to pass the object I am having a hard time trying to use both the circleType and cylinderType classes with the passed object. I am not sure how to work this question properly, but I am trying to figure out how to use two different classes in a comparison function.

```
bool equalVolume(const circleType&, const cylinderType& ct)
{
    if (ct.CalcVolume != Calvolume())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You made some typos correct them first, then it will work if both `circelType` and `cylinderType` have `calcVolume` function

Comment: You probably mean `return (cleft.CalcVolume() == cright.CalcVolume());` as the body of your function `bool equalVolume(const circleType&cleft, const cylinderType&cright)`

Comment: You might also redesign your application so that both `class circleType` and `class cylinderType` inherit from a *common* superclass `GeometricalObject` declaring some `virtual double CalcVolume(void) const;` method. Then you just need a `bool sameValue(const GeometricalObject&left, GeometricalObject&right);` function

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple problems with your implementation. You receive both shapes, but the `circleType` has no variant name. Then I see you tried to call the function `calcVolume` with no variable. How can you calculate the volume of nothing? Well, you can't. You have to use the name of the circle and refer to it.

```
//                                 v---- Give a name to your circle
bool equalVolume(const CircleType& myCircle, const CylinderType& myCylinder) {
//      v---- Call calcVolume with myCircle
    if (myCircle.calcVolume() != myCylinder.calcVolume()) {
//      call with the cylinder --^
        return false
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

By the way, since the comparison is already an expression of type `bool`, you can shrink your function to that:

```
bool equalVolume(const CircleType& myCircle, const CylinderType& myCylinder) {
    return myCircle.calcVolume() == myCylinder.calcVolume();
}
```

---

I would rather create a function that returns the volume and leave the implementation to the user. It would look like that:

```
using volume_t = double;

struct Circle {
    volume_t volume() const {
        // return volume here
    }
};

struct Cylinder {
    volume_t volume() const {
        // return volume here
    }
};
```

And then, instead of using the `isVolumeEqual` function, just do that:

```
if (myCircle.volume() == myCylinder.volume()) {
    // code here ...
}
```

If you really want to implement the volume equal function, I would do it like that:

```
template<typename S1, typename S2>
auto volumeEqual(const S1& s1, const S2& s2) -> decltype(s1.volume() == s2.volume()) {
    return s1.volume() == s2.volume();
}
```

That way, you implement a `volumeEqual` for all possible shapes that has the `volume()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have thought it might look something like this:

```
bool equalVolume(const circleType& cir, const cylinderType& cyl)
{
    return cir.CalcVolume == cyl.CalcVolume;
}
```

As another user has pointed out, I'd probably add a volume() getter function and use that instead of directly accessing the CalcVolume (which is probably a data member).

**PS:** Writing a function to compare volumes like this looks superfluous because you could always just compare the volumes inside an if() condition instead.

Comment: A function is a good idea, it can help with code readability and it could be used in algorithms